# Webpack wont compile jsx file with react

Tags: webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to get my webpack environment to compile jsx/es6 syntax back into to regular es5 javascript. When I run the "start" script however it gives me a syntax error pointing towards the ReactDom.render method.
[image]

I've been looking around and I think that I've set up my webpack.config.js incorrectly.

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  }
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bable": {
    "presets": [
      "env",
      "react",
      "stage-2"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.13",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "react": "^16.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development"
  }
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Do you have a `.babelrc` that enables those Babel presets? You' need to both install them and tell Babel to enable them.

Comment: I don't have a babelrc bc I thought it was optional. Which it is because artem showed me the way. Are there any drawbacks to doing it this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use babel preset `react` and `es2015` in loader options  statement, like this:

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      presets: ['react', 'es2015']
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `env` uses the latest preset in webpack.

Comment: I like this way because it just gets rid of one more file plus it looks like it belongs there right? I mean if your declaring what being changed and how its being changed it makes sense for it all to be in the same place right?

Comment: You should use `['react', 'env']` since those are what you actually have in your `package.json` dependencies.

Comment: ah ok im learning webpack right now after coming from create-react-app so i never really learned the tool seemed like a good time since webpack 4 just came out